# How to get current page in my WP7 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to get the active instance of the current page in my Windows Phone 7 app? I have been reading documentation and trying to figure it out to no avail.

In my example I am running a global loop which calls a public method of the active page.

For example, the application loads to `Page1.xaml`, if my loop fires with this page active I need to fire a loop found in the Page1 code-behind. If Page2 is active I will need to be firing a different method in the Page2 code-behind file.

NOTE: My methods in the individual pages cannot be static because I require access to instance variables. So not only do I need the active page (which could be achieved through a variable of some sort), but I need the *instance* of the current page.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can get the current page from the root frame. The default `App` class that is generated in the project has a `RootFrame` property that is already of type `PhoneApplicationFrame`. The value of the `Content` property is the current page and can be cast to `PhoneApplicationPage`.

```
var currentPage = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
```

The `RootVisual` property on the `Application` class references the same frame, but is a `UIElement`, so you could use the following instead:

```
var currentPage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;
```

Comment: Using this technique, how would I proceed to call a method in the PhoneApplicationPage? It does not allow currentPage.myMethod();

Comment: You can call public methods on the resulting page in the same way that you would any other class. To call methods on your own page, you would need to cast the result to that specific class to be able to access it's public methods.

Comment: Am I missing something here? `var currentPage = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
            currentPage = currentPage as Namespace.MyPage;`

Answer (score 5):

You can get the current XAML page URL using NavigationService.CurrentSource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.currentsource(v=VS.92).aspx

However, to get the instance of the current page itself I think you'll need to maintain this yourself - one way would be to inherit all your pages from a shared abstract class which overrides OnNavigatedTo and then uses this as an opportunity to record itself with a singleton (maybe your App class)